# How to set relative path to current folder?

Tags: html

Lets say I am currently at:
`http://example.com/folder/page.html`

Is it possible to create a relative link on this page that points to `http://example.com/folder/` without specifying `folder` anywhere? (And using only HTML.)

**UPDATE:**
**As it turned out `./` works only in non-strict doctype mode, while `.` works in both modes, so it is still a better answer in my opinion :) 
Thanks everybody.**

Comment: Why would someone create a relative path to the current directory when by default just the name of the file itself in href assumes the current directory?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Just dot is working.  The doctype makes a difference however as sometimes the ./ is fine as well.

```
<a href=".">Link to this folder</a>
```

Answer (score 55):

For anyone who has found this thread, addressing relative paths has always created arguments over what is correct or not.

Depending on where you use the path to be addressed, it will depend on how you address the path.

Generally :

`.` and `./` do the same thing, however you wouldn't use `.` with a file name. Otherwise you will have the browser requesting `.filename.ext` as a file from the server. The proper method would be `./filename.ext`.

`../` addresses the path up one level from the current folder. If you were in the path `/cheese/crackers/yummy.html`, and your link code asked for `../butter/spread.html` in the document `yummy.html`, then you would be addressing the path `/cheese/butter/spread.html`, as far as the server was concerned.

`/` will always address the *root* of the site.

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
 ../
```

to mean up one level. If you have a page called **page2.html** in the same folder as **page.html** then the relative path is:

```
 page2.html.
```

If you have **page2.html** at the same level with folder then the path is:

```
  ../page2.html
```

Comment: That answered the question I came here to look for, how to find a page in the same folder.

Answer (score 11):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <a href="./">Folder directory</a> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope. This goes one level up. I need current folder.

Comment: No it is not :) The single dot is the answer.

Comment: I test it in both IE and Firefox and "." was the same as "./"  HTML 4.01 Transitional.  Is is a doc type issue?

Comment: Hm, that's could be it. I am using strict, should have mentioned that probably.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the below seem to work

./

.

Comment: Still not right, this goes one level up, which is not what he's asking... See Bullines answer

Comment: ./ going one level up seems to be nonsense to me. why does it do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="./">Folder</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The top answer is not clear enough. here is what worked for me: The correct format should look like this if you want to point to the actual file:

```
 <a href="./page.html">
```

This will have you point to that file within the same folder if you are on the page `http://example.com/folder/index.html`