# Link to index page of website

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, href

Is there a way to link to the index page of a website without specifying the name of the index page or the full website URL?

I have this:

```
<a href="index.htm">Home</a>
```

But when I click the link, my address bar shows:

```
mydomain.com/index.html
```

I would like it to show:

```
mydomain.com
```

Can I do that without putting the full URL (`mydomain.com`) in the `href`? If so, how?

For future viewers, I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/296873/785745) helpful.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Any `href` preceded by a slash is relative the root directory.

It should be noted that when viewing a webpage from a local hard drive in a browser, this will cause the link not to function.

Comment: Is there an equally simple way for sub-directories? e.g. from `mydomain.com/foo/bar.html` to `mydomain.com/foo/`?

Comment: You can use `<a href="/#foo">Link Text</a>` to link to a specific part of your page as well.

Answer (score 15):

I know this post is old and has an answer. But here is my contribution that also supports index that is not exactly in the root directory

to goto

```
mydomain.com/index.html
```

without index.html showing in address bar

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

this will always point to mydomain.com no matter where the directory your file was saved to.

to point to the index in a directory use this:

```
<a href="./">Home</a>
```

this will point to mydomain.com/subdir for mydomain.com/subdir/index.html while the accepted answer will always point to mydomain.com (and this is not always the desired action)

Comment: When viewing a webpage from a local hard drive in a browser, this will cause the link to show the folder in most browsers.

Comment: That's interesting. But I guess that is because opening a HTML file via file:/// doesn't load index.* automatically for current directory.

Comment: I don't know why whats wrong with mine. After viewing another part of the web, when I click home, it does not go to index.html part. I have tried: <a href="/">home</a>, <a href="index.html">home</a>, and also <a href="./">home</a>. Nothing works. But I noticed, when I clicked the home button, the link add a "#" in the last button I clicked. What was that?

Comment: @AgungSudrajatSupriatna this post is old and your comment isn't really related to my answer. Getting # could mean a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ".htaccess" file and upload to your host public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.yourwebsite.com.ph/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What did this do...now my site is utterly horked. Guess it serves me right for pasting something I don't understand into my .htaccess file. But come on. Even after deleting the offending code it's still messed up. Every page I try to go to has the .html stripped off, and I can't access anything.

Comment: OK, after clearing all my cache it's better. It probably didn't help that I left "yourwebsite" as-is lol. But I'm too afraid to try it again. And now I can't change my downvote. Sorry.