# When clicking Home button, url is showing full path instead of just index.php

Tags: php, html, hosting

I just uploaded my htdocs folder to public_html in my web hosting service, and the website works correctly, but when pressing the Home button the URL displays the entire server path.

```
<div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="shop.php">Shop</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="local_stores.php">Local Stores</a></li>
   <li><a href="login.php">Store Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I expect the Home button to bring me back to mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com/home1/company/public_html/mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

When you just enter the file name, html always prepends the path.
Try using `<a href=“/index.php“>Home<a>`

The / tells the browser to go for domain.tld/index.php

Comment: It didn't work :/ it doesn't prepend for another of the other links. Only for index.php even when I use the /

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! When in development using XAMP and text editors, you use "index.php" and "otherpage.php" in the a tags. But when in the hosting service, to go back to the "index.php", the href value should be "/" because it'll automatically look for the index.php in the directory it's in.

I used this stack thread to solve the issue:

[Link to index page of website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563352/link-to-index-page-of-website)

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying to go back to home page try this

`Home`   use only / in your href="/"

this is indicate to index.php and it will not show in your url