# How to give path of images in html

Tags: html, image

Suppose I have a folder named Imp and in it,I have a webpage folder and a images folder.I have my webpage in webpage folder and my images in images folder. So, how can I give the path of an image s4.jpg present in images folder from a webpage in webpages folder..i mean what should I write in the src attribute of img tag?

Comment: `src='../imagesFolder/s4.jpg'`

Comment: without seeing your directory structure, i'm not surprised.

Comment: src="//yourDomain.ex/Imp/images/s4.jpg" (This is an absolute path)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic HTML - how to set relative path to current folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/basic-html-how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You have two kind of path to access your image :

1. Relative `src="../images/s4.jpg"` (up to parent is relative from where your page is display, here the page is run from direct sub directory).
2. Absolute `src="/images/s4.jpg"`.

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't seen your answers in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If In documents folder of c drive you have made a folder imp and in the imp, you have made another folder named - "images"

then your code should be -

```
<img src="../imp/images/filename.ext>
```