# Cannot add js file using script tag

Tags: javascript, html, http-status-code-404, relative-path

This seems like a rather dumb question to ask but I would like to resolve this quickly and start working.I have a folder in which my html resides and I have the javascript files in a seperate folder called `js`.I have tried to add the script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmaps.js">
```

and I have also tried like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/gmaps.js">
```

I have even tried like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/gmaps.js">
```

As far as I understand either of the first two should work:

```
 / root folder
./ current folder
../one folder up
```

The paths of the files are

```
 /home/anr/Desktop/maps/server/client/js/gmaps.js
 /home/anr/Desktop/maps/server/client/google_maps.html
```

## UPDATE:

The js file has window.onload and it also creates another script tag programmatically and adds it to the dom,after moving to the external script file I find that the map does not load

Comment: What are the full paths of the HTML file and the script files?

Comment: show the directory structure of js and current file

Comment: the first one would work just fine .... maybe its cuz you are not closing your script with </script>

Comment: the first one can't work

Comment: Closing the script tag is the problem,the closing script tag also got exported to my js file...fixed that

Comment: If the gmaps.js is loaded on google_maps.html. then the first two codes should be work with the </script> tag

Comment: @VinodVT yes it is,how to ensure that it loads as the first thing when the page loads should I use `window.onload` or `$.document.ready()`

Comment: @user2309862 if you just include the script on html page it should load. no need for any other javascript

Comment: @VinodVT should I gzip my Javascript,I have already minified it and is adding at the bottom of body better than adding it to head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you are closing your  tag as well. Once you have the correct relative path, your syntax should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="relative_path_here"></script>
```

The following link could be helpful for setting the relative path in HTML:
[Basic HTML - how to set relative path to current folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/basic-html-how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to close your script tag with a  on the first example, which should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmaps.js"></script>
```

The script tag should be closed

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmaps.js"></script>` **Tag should be closed**

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem but not with the path. My problem is the encoding of the html file in my demo, change encoding to ASNI to fix problem.