# Relative Link to Subfolder?

Tags: php, html

I have the link: www.mysite.com/jobs/stackoverflow

And I want to get this link using a relative file path: www.mysite.com/jobs/stackoverflow/123

Right now I am getting the current url using PHP and then appending '/123' onto the end of the 'href' value to access the subfolder. This method works but I was wondering if there is a way to write a relative link that will link to a subfolder. At first I thought it would be as easy as typing:

```
<a href="123">Link</a>
```

but that replaces the 'stackoverflow' part rather than appending it onto the end.

I'm fine with using the PHP solution and I am not looking for a javascript or jQuery solution, I was just curious to see if there was a simple way to do this using only HTML.

Comment: you can use htaccess rewriting, this allows you to setup rules for urls. so what you could do in the end is have href="/123" and setup a rule so that this type of url maps to www.mysite.com/jobs/stackoverflow/123  Look at this link: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: or create a "router" in php. Similar to my above comment. Only using php to break apart the url or determine where the page should actually go.

Comment: or pending on your file structure. Relative pathing can done with ./123 where the ./ means the rest of the directory path that this file or path is located.

Answer (score -1):

I found someone linking to the current directory like this:

[Basic HTML - how to set relative path to current folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/basic-html-how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder)

so putting the `./` before the `123` in your link might work.