# css, javascript, images path in html file

Tags: html, path

I have a few folders like Pages(html files go here), Javascript(script files), CSS(css files), images.

In my html file I wanna give path and I am not sure how I am supposed to give it.
If the file is going to be in the same folder the following will work

```
<img src="a_logo.gif" alt=""/>
```

But in my case I tried

```
<img src="../images/a_logo.gif" alt=""/>
```

which didn't work.
Any leads?

Thanks

Folder Structure

```
Folder A
|
|-----Folder VT
      |
      |-----HTML(a.html)
      |-----JS
      |-----CSS
      |-----images
```

Inside a.html I wanna add js,css,images.

Comment: I suspect a typo error may be the issue or may be the incorrect folder structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic HTML - how to set relative path to current folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/basic-html-how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder)

Comment: `../` is up one folder level from where the html file is, then it looks for the images folder

Comment: you haven't said where the images go or how your pages are served - ie do you have url rewriting? basically, if you are using relative paths, it will be from the url the page is served to the url where the image is served

Comment: a.html inside HTML folder?

Comment: yes. a.html inside html folder

Answer (score 1):

Only use of `images/a_logo.gif` will help to run code properly,You dont need to write `../images/`
so here is a code:
 `<img src="images/a.gif" alt=""/>`

Also, check if given images are present image folder and naming convention provided are right.

Comment: thank you. img src="..\images\a.gif" worked to me finally.