# Purpose of ./ before call to a stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, html-head

I saw the below head section in a page and I don't understand the purpose of the **./** before the stylesheet call. I checked the directory for the site and the stylesheet is in the same directory as the index page.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: `.` means current directory.

Comment: Purpose of ./ before call to a stylesheet?

It no way effects the directory if u remove that nothing happens and if u use that then the same nothing happen.

But in case u remove / that means the file would use as .style.css. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` refers to the current directory (that the HTML page is in) and `./styles.css` refers to a file called `styles.css` in the current directory. See here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/24340516/8595398