# Trouble with links in html

Tags: html

I been trying to create a navbar on my website, the problem is that when I create the folder with the html pages and when I click on it the page says this on the url C:/User/jorge/OneDrive/Desktop/rootfolder/pages/pages/education.html.
Browser says this: Your file was not found
It may have been moved or deleted.
I am using Google chrome to create website.
This is my code if needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Social Work | Home Page</title>

</head>

<body>

   <nav>

       <ul>

        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="pages/agency.html">Agency</a></li>

        <li><a href="pages/education.html">Education</a></li>

        <li><a href="pages/resource.html">Resource</a></li>

         <li><a href="pages/video.html">Videos</a></li>

       </ul>

   </nav>

   <h1>Education Page</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not found means just that, it wasn't found.  Is the file there?

Comment: Yes I saved it and everything. I don't know why it says that.

Comment: are you sure you have your files under `pages/pages`folder? because that's where the browser is looking for it. You have a pages subfolder under the pages folder?

Comment: `/pages/pages` I reckon you are already in pages here. Try changing `href="pages/agency.html"` etc. to `href="agency.html"` and see if it works

Comment: @user12331718: And you've *confirmed* that this *exact path* (including the doubled use of "pages" in the folders) is correct?  Can you show us?

Comment: Yes it worked thank you so much. Can you explain what was the issue for future reference.

Comment: links starting with `./` or nothing at all are relative to your current location. You can read up on relative and absolute links for more info

Comment: This info can be found here: [Basic HTML - how to set relative path to current folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/basic-html-how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder) Therefor I vote this as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Just give
href="education.html" in a tag
Or
href="/education.html" in a tag