# Images doesn't load when I create a new card and add it to It's parent with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm currently trying to populate a template with the array that I get from my localStorage. **Everything displays fine in the cards except for the images**. I have checked the URL paths and it is the right path because I had dummy cards in the markup just to check that the image path is correct before I cleared the innerHTML with calling generateShoppingCart(cart). **In the browser dev tools, it says it could not load images and doesn't show any errors**. Is there anything I'm doing wrong and is there a solution to this problem? I highly appreciate any feedback.

**This is the HTML markup:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Shopping Cart Page</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="./img/clothing/hoodys/hoody-mockup.webp" as="image">
    <meta name="description" content="Tailwindcss startup files for a new project">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="./scripts/shoppingCart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="flex items-center justify-between">
                <div class="md:hidden cursor-pointer" data-nav-toggle>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h7" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <a href="home-page.html" class="flex items-center"><img class="h-10 md:h-14"
                        src="./img/logo/pig-xxl.png" alt="bargaintravels logo"><span
                        class="font-bold md:text-2xl">BargainTravels</span></a>
                <div class="flex gap-6 items-center">
                    <ul class="flex hidden dropdown-menu" data-nav>
                        <li><a class="flex gap-1" href="city-page.html">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                        d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z" />
                                </svg> <span class="">Trips</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="about-page.html">About</a></li>

                        <li><a href="shop-page.html">Shop</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div>
                        <a href="shopping-cart-page.html">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                stroke="currentColor">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                    d="M16 11V7a4 4 0 00-8 0v4M5 9h14l1 12H4L5 9z" />
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden overlay" data-overlay></div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="mt-fixed-sm md:mt-fixed-md">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
                <div class="spacer grid-spacer md:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-16">
                    <div class="md:col-span-2 grid-spacer" data-shopping-cart>
                        <!-- card -->

                        <div class="cart-item">
                            <div class="col-span-1">
                                <img src="./img/clothing/hoodys/hoody-mockup.webp" alt="" loading="lazy">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-span-2 flex flex-col">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 class="font-semibold text-lg md:text-2xl">Hoody</h3>
                                    <p class="text-gray-500 font-medium mt-2">R450</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="more-info">
                                    <div class="flex gap-4 items-center">
                                        <label for="number">Quantity:</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="0" value="1" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <button>Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- card -->
                        <div class="cart-item">
                            <div class="col-span-1">
                                <img src="./img/clothing/longsleeves/long-sleeve-mockup.webp" alt="" loading="lazy">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-span-2 flex flex-col">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 class="font-semibold text-lg md:text-2xl">Longsleeve</h3>
                                    <p class="text-gray-500 font-medium mt-2">R450</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="more-info">
                                    <div class="flex gap-4 items-center">
                                        <label for="number">Quantity:</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="0" value="1" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <button>Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- card -->
                        <div class="cart-item">
                            <div class="col-span-1">
                                <img src="./img/clothing/pullovers/pullover-mockup.webp" alt="" loading="lazy">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-span-2 flex flex-col">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 class="font-semibold text-lg md:text-2xl">Pullover</h3>
                                    <p class="text-gray-500 font-medium mt-2">R450</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="more-info">
                                    <div class="flex gap-4 items-center">
                                        <label for="number">Quantity:</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="0" value="1" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <button>Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- card -->
                        <div class="cart-item">
                            <div class="col-span-1">
                                <img src="./img/clothing/t-shirts/t-shirt-mockup.webp" alt="" loading="lazy">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-span-2 flex flex-col">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 class="font-semibold text-lg md:text-2xl">T-shirt</h3>
                                    <p class="text-gray-500 font-medium mt-2">R450</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="more-info">
                                    <div class="flex gap-4 items-center">
                                        <label for="number">Quantity:</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="0" value="1" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <button>Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- card -->
                        <div class="cart-item">
                            <div class="col-span-1">
                                <img src="./img/clothing/jackets/jacket-mockup.webp" alt="" loading="lazy">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-span-2 flex flex-col">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 class="font-semibold text-lg md:text-2xl">Jacket</h3>
                                    <p class="text-gray-500 font-medium mt-2">R450</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="more-info">
                                    <div class="flex gap-4 items-center">
                                        <label for="number">Quantity:</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="0" value="1" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <button>Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md:col-span-1">
                        <h2 class="h3">Order Summary</h2>
                        <div class="spacer flow-content font-bold">
                            <div class="flex justify-between">
                                <p>Subtotal</p>
                                <span class="text-gray-500">R200</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex justify-between">
                                <p>Shipping Cost</p>
                                <span class="text-gray-500">Free</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex justify-between">
                                <p>Order Total</p>
                                <span class="text-gray-500">R950</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="spacer btn w-full">Checkout</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="bg-accent text-white md:text-center">
        <div class="container grid-spacer">

            <ul class="footer-row">
                <li><a href="about-page.html" class="footer-links-transiton">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links-transiton">Work for us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links-transiton">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links-transiton">Terms & conditons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links-transiton">Privacy policy</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="footer-row">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                        Facebook
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6" height="24" width="24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                            data-prefix="fab" data-icon="facebook-f" class="svg-inline--fa fa-facebook-f fa-w-10"
                            role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                        Instagram
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6" height="24" width="24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                            data-prefix="fab" data-icon="instagram" class="svg-inline--fa fa-instagram fa-w-14"
                            role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M224.1 141c-63.6 0-114.9 51.3-114.9 114.9s51.3 114.9 114.9 114.9S339 319.5 339 255.9 287.7 141 224.1 141zm0 189.6c-41.1 0-74.7-33.5-74.7-74.7s33.5-74.7 74.7-74.7 74.7 33.5 74.7 74.7-33.6 74.7-74.7 74.7zm146.4-194.3c0 14.9-12 26.8-26.8 26.8-14.9 0-26.8-12-26.8-26.8s12-26.8 26.8-26.8 26.8 12 26.8 26.8zm76.1 27.2c-1.7-35.9-9.9-67.7-36.2-93.9-26.2-26.2-58-34.4-93.9-36.2-37-2.1-147.9-2.1-184.9 0-35.8 1.7-67.6 9.9-93.9 36.1s-34.4 58-36.2 93.9c-2.1 37-2.1 147.9 0 184.9 1.7 35.9 9.9 67.7 36.2 93.9s58 34.4 93.9 36.2c37 2.1 147.9 2.1 184.9 0 35.9-1.7 67.7-9.9 93.9-36.2 26.2-26.2 34.4-58 36.2-93.9 2.1-37 2.1-147.8 0-184.8zM398.8 388c-7.8 19.6-22.9 34.7-42.6 42.6-29.5 11.7-99.5 9-132.1 9s-102.7 2.6-132.1-9c-19.6-7.8-34.7-22.9-42.6-42.6-11.7-29.5-9-99.5-9-132.1s-2.6-102.7 9-132.1c7.8-19.6 22.9-34.7 42.6-42.6 29.5-11.7 99.5-9 132.1-9s102.7-2.6 132.1 9c19.6 7.8 34.7 22.9 42.6 42.6 11.7 29.5 9 99.5 9 132.1s2.7 102.7-9 132.1z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                        Twitter
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6" height="24" width="24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                            data-prefix="fab" data-icon="twitter" class="svg-inline--fa fa-twitter fa-w-16" role="img"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                        Youtube
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6" height="24" width="24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                            data-prefix="fab" data-icon="youtube" class="svg-inline--fa fa-youtube fa-w-18" role="img"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M549.655 124.083c-6.281-23.65-24.787-42.276-48.284-48.597C458.781 64 288 64 288 64S117.22 64 74.629 75.486c-23.497 6.322-42.003 24.947-48.284 48.597-11.412 42.867-11.412 132.305-11.412 132.305s0 89.438 11.412 132.305c6.281 23.65 24.787 41.5 48.284 47.821C117.22 448 288 448 288 448s170.78 0 213.371-11.486c23.497-6.321 42.003-24.171 48.284-47.821 11.412-42.867 11.412-132.305 11.412-132.305s0-89.438-11.412-132.305zm-317.51 213.508V175.185l142.739 81.205-142.739 81.201z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p>&copy; 2021 Bargaintravels. All rights reserved.</p>

        </div>
    </footer>
  
</body>

</html>
```

**This is the JAVASCRIPT file:**

```
const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SHOPPING_CART"));
const cardParent = document.querySelector("[data-shopping-cart]");

const generateShoppingCart = cart => {
  cardParent.innerHTML = "";
  cart.forEach(templateCard);
};

const templateCard = item => {
  const { image, name, price, quantity } = item;

  const card = `
          <div class="cart-item">
          <div class="col-span-1">
              <img class="mockup" src="${image}" alt="A mockup of our ${name}">
          </div>
          <div class="col-span-2 flex flex-col">
              <div>
                  <h3 class="font-semibold text-lg md:text-2xl">${name}</h3>
                  <p class="text-gray-500 font-medium mt-2">R${price}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="more-info">
                  <div class="flex gap-4 items-center">
                      <label for="number">Quantity:</label>
                      <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="0" value="${quantity}" required>
                  </div>
                  <button>Remove</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
          `;

  cardParent.innerHTML += card;
};

generateShoppingCart(cart);
```

**Here is an example of one of the items in the array that I get back from my local storage**

```
{
    "name": "Longsleeve",
    "price": 250,
    "quantity": 1,
    "size": "XS",
    "color": "White",
    "image": "./img/clothing/longsleeves/long-sleeve-mockup.webp"
  }
```

Comment: It's the dot slash at the beginning of the image - Read the bolded update posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set relative path to current folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder)

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand. So you are saying that this ` "image": "./img/clothing/longsleeves/long-sleeve-mockup.webp" ` is the wrong relative path? Then what should it be? Because when I create a dummy card then that relative path seems to be correct before I edit the innerHTML.

Comment: Hey I figured the problem out so I thought I would just update it incase someone in the future comes across this. I realized that I should use the relative path from my dist  folder because I'm using parcel instead of the normal folder.  Hope this helps someone in the future 